# Joda timeField taglib formatting

Tags: grails, jodatime

using: Joda-Time Grails plugin.
using: DateTime in domain object.

How to get only time component without milliseconds in a GSP input field?

Using this:

```
<joda:timeField type="date" name="time" value="${myDate}" />
```

I get for example: 17:00:00.000

Where I would like to have: 17:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<joda:time value="${myDate}">
    <joda:format value="${it}" pattern="HH:mm"/>
</joda:time>
```

[`<joda:time>`](http://gpc.github.io/grails-joda-time/ref/Tags/time.html) and [`<joda:format>`](http://gpc.github.io/grails-joda-time/ref/Tags/format.html) can be used as above.